# How to validate_presence_of with condition in a nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, nested-attributes

I have model Question, Answer and AnswerDetail.

**Answer:**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answer_details, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer_details, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_associated :answer_details
end
```

**AnswerDetail:**

```
class AnswerDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :question
  validates_presence_of :answer_field, :if => lambda {isrequired == true}, :message => "This is required field"
end
```

The `isrequired` field is from the model Question.

**Question:**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :answer_detail
end
```

The AnswerDetal model has the `question_id` and `answer_id` field on it. I want to filter the `answer_field` if the `isrequire` field from Question model is equal to true? How I will do this? How to access the has_one association's attribute inside model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before, although I've not got the code handy right now:

---

**Nested**

From what I remember, you can actually put the validation in the nested model:

```
#app/models/question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :answer_field, presence: true, if: lambda {isrequired == true}
end
```

I highly recommend using the new [`validates`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) syntax

--

[**inverse_of**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations)

I'm sure I had to use `inverse_of` somewhere in the code I had (it's locked in a private GitHub repo sorry).

`inverse_of` basically includes the associated model in your current model. Much like how you've found the effectiveness of `self.question.isrequired`:

```
#app/models/answer_detail.rb
class AnswerDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question, inverse_of: :answer_detail
  validates :answer_field, presence: true, if: lambda { question.isrequired == true }
end

#app/models/question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :answer_detail, inverse_of: :question
end
```

However, [good news for you](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence):

[image]

Comment: I am a little confused to your answer? Do I need to put `validates :answer_field, presence: true, if: lambda {isrequired == true}` on Question model? Why?

Answer (score 1):

## This is not the answer, this is how I would troubleshoot

Inspect in:

```
  validates_presence_of :answer_field, :if => lambda {isrequired == true}, :message => "This is required field"
```

What variables you have available, you can do this with `pry-rails` gem. Like this:

```
  validates_presence_of :answer_field, :if => lambda {binding.pry; isrequired == true}, :message => "This is required field"
```

When trying to save a question you will get a interactive console(in the server terminal window) where you can print values like `self` or do this:

```
  validates_presence_of :answer_field, :if => lambda {|record| binding.pry; isrequired == true}, :message => "This is required field"
```

And print `record`.

Then you can try finding where `Question` is stored with: `self.question` or `record.question`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `self.question.isrequired` and it is working. But maybe you have other nice suggestion to do the error validation. Thank you.